# Identifying a website with geometric construction challenges of increasing difficulty

Tags: geometry, reference-request

A few years ago, I found a website that challenged the user to perform geometric constructions (e.g., duplicate a line segment, bisect an angle, duplicate an angle, and so on) in the minimum number of steps.
Each problem listed the tools that could be used (e.g., compass, straightedge, ruler, etc.), and each became became progressively harder.

Does anyone know this website?

Thanks!

Comment: did they mean this? https://www.euclidea.xyz/

Comment: Try this search: https://www.google.com/search?q=gepmetry+construction+website&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-1

Comment: @David Quinn:  Euclidea is similar, does the same thing as the one I used.  It may actually be the same one just made cumbersome and irritating.

Answer (score 0):

https://sciencevsmagic.net/geo/ has some compass and straight-edge geometry challenges with step count targets

Comment: @amWhy the question specifically asks for a website link

Comment: Indeed, @Claude. Thanks for pointing that out.  I've deleted my earlier comment.